rust tokio primitive that would make two threads wait until an event happens and then continue but if the event already happened then don't even stop
I am looking for a primitive that would make two threads wait until an event happens and then continue but if the event already happened then don't even stop waiting.
I imagine that a watch channel may work but that does not seem very idiomatic.
Pure tokio notify may not work as an event may happen earlier than thread starts waiting for notification. So maybe adding a boolean wrapped in Mutex is necessary. But I want a standard idiomatic solution as I imagine the problem is not new. Basically, I want code similar to the following to work and have no race conditions.
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Notify;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let notify = Arc::new(Notify::new());
    let notify2 = notify.clone();
    let notify3 = notify.clone();

    println!("sending notification");
    notify.notify_waiters();
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        notify2.notified().await;
        println!("received notification 1");
    });
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        notify3.notified().await;
        println!("received notification 2");
    });

    // Wait for task to receive notification.
    handle.await.unwrap();
}


Here's a potential solution leveraging a combination of semaphores and atomics
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::sync::Semaphore;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let event = Arc::new(EventNotifier::default());
    let mut tasks = Vec::with_capacity(2);
    for _ in 0..2 {
        let task = tokio::spawn({
            let event = event.clone();
            async move {
                // wait for event
                event.notified().await;
                // do something afterwards
            }
        });
        tasks.push(task);
    }
    event.notify();
    for t in tasks {
        let _ = t.await;
    }
}

struct EventNotifier {
    // atomic state of event, first bit is a boolean flag, 
    // and the rest is the number of task, waiting for the event to happen
    atomic: AtomicUsize,
    // just an asynchronous signaling mechanism
    permits: Semaphore,
}

impl Default for EventNotifier {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            atomic: AtomicUsize::new(0),
            permits: Semaphore::new(0),
        }
    }
}

impl EventNotifier {
    pub fn notify(&self) {
        let mut value = self.atomic.load(Ordering::Acquire);
        let waiters = loop {
            let waiters = value >> 1; // get the number of waiting tasks
            // try to update the state of event to being complete
            if let Err(v) =
                self.atomic
                    .compare_exchange(value, 1, Ordering::Release, Ordering::Acquire)
            {
                // if some other task registered itself as waiting the CAS will fail
                value = v;
            } else {
                break waiters;
            }
        };
        // notify all the waiting tasks about event completion
        self.permits.add_permits(waiters);
    }

    pub async fn notified(&self) {
        let mut value = self.atomic.load(Ordering::Acquire);
        loop {
            // if event already completed, just return
            if value & 1 == 1 {
                return;
            }
            // otherwise try to register itself as waiting task 
            let waiters = (value >> 1) + 1;
            let flag = value & 1;
            let new = flag | (waiters << 1);
            // if the event completed or some other task registered itself as completed retry the above check
            if let Err(v) =
                self.atomic
                    .compare_exchange(value, new, Ordering::Release, Ordering::Acquire)
            {
                value = v
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        // wait for event completion notification asynchronously 
        let _ = self.permits.acquire().await;
    }
}

The implementation should handle all the possible cases avoiding race conditions.

Looks promising. Would be great if you could add a stress-test similar the one I did with random delays inserted in different places. What I am worried about in your solution is that after the last atomic compare exchange and before permits.acquire() the event happens and we miss it. And also note that correct test may only be mutithreaded and you potentially did single-threaded, which eliminates many possible deadlocks


"What I am worried about in your solution is that after the last atomic compare exchange and before permits.acquire() the event happens and we miss it".

No, we don't, if compare exchange succeeded, it's guaranteed that the current task registered itself for future permit. If the event happens before call to acquire, acquire will immediately return, as the notify adds exactly as many permits to semaphore as there have been registered tasks so far.

The implementation is intended to work in multithreaded context, there's very little point in going through all this trouble for single threaded one, bool with Notify will do the job just fine.

you are probably right. I'll test it and accept. Meanwhile upvoting

Here is a sketch of a solution with watch channels. It seems working correctly and I will proceed for now. But I would be grateful for a more idiomatic solution with some sort of an analogue of condvar.
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use tokio::sync::watch;
use tokio::time::{self, Duration};

#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 4)]
async fn main() {
    const TEST_COUNT: usize = 10_000;

    // We'll run the same "trigger an event once, let two tasks wait for it" flow 10k times.
    for i in 0..TEST_COUNT {
        let (tx, rx) = watch::channel(false);
        let mut rx1 = rx.clone();
        let mut rx2 = rx.clone();

        // Task A
        let handle1 = tokio::spawn(async move {
            // Random short sleep to scramble scheduling.
            let delay = thread_rng().gen_range(0..2);
            time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;

            // Check if event has already happened.
            // the explicit “borrow” check is only an optimization that avoids an unnecessary async suspension
            // in case the receiver is already up-to-date
            if !*rx1.borrow() {
                let delay = thread_rng().gen_range(0..2);
                time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;
                // If not, await first change to `true`.
                // Under the hood, each watch::Receiver has an internal sequence number indicating the version
                // of the channel’s state it has seen. Every time the sender calls tx.send(...),
                // this version is incremented. When you call changed().await, if the receiver’s version is out of date
                // (i.e., less than the channel’s current version), changed() returns immediately.
                // This is how the watch channel prevents “missing updates” even if the change happens
                // between your “check” and your “await.”
                rx1.changed().await.expect("watch channel closed");
            }
        });

        // Task B
        let handle2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
            let delay = thread_rng().gen_range(0..2);
            time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;

            if !*rx2.borrow() {
                let delay = thread_rng().gen_range(0..2);
                time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;
                rx2.changed().await.expect("watch channel closed");
            }
        });

        // Random short sleep before triggering event.
        // This tries to ensure the tasks might already be waiting ...
        let delay = thread_rng().gen_range(0..4);
        time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay)).await;

        // "Event has happened"
        tx.send(true).expect("watch channel closed");

        // Wait for both tasks to confirm receipt of the `true` state.
        handle1.await.unwrap();
        handle2.await.unwrap();

        // Print progress occasionally
        if (i + 1) % 1000 == 0 {
            println!("Finished iteration {}", i + 1);
        }
    }

    println!("All {} iterations completed successfully.", TEST_COUNT);
}


I don't have much experience in Async, so take my words with a grain of salt.
I think for what you're describing the only way is as you described, to use a Arc<Mutex<T>> wrapper for some sort of state you keep track of in your threads.
This code would look something like this:
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::Mutex;

async fn notified_functions(name: &str, shared_state: Arc<Mutex<bool>>) {
    loop {
        if *shared_state.lock().await {
            break;
        }
    }
    println!("Notified[{name}].");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let shared_state = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));

    *shared_state.lock().await = true;

    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    handles.push(
        tokio::spawn(notified_functions("1", shared_state.clone()))
    );
    handles.push(
        tokio::spawn(notified_functions("2", shared_state.clone()))
    );

    //Wait for the threads to join.
    for i in handles {
        i.await.unwrap();
    }
}

You can look into more option in case you need to send messages and have better performance, crossbeam and flume would be a good start.
But I have zero experience with those and they might still have the race condition problem you were trying to fix.
I hope this helped. I know it's not the most satisfying answer but I think this is the idiomatic solution you were looking for and actually guessed on your original post.

What you did here is a busy loop or spinlock. That’s one way to solve the problem and it is used. It usually has good latency but takes computer resources so is only acceptable for a a small time period. I am looking rather for a primitive that parks the thread/task and then notifies when it’s ready which is a different async pattern

@NikolayZarikov You don't need the loop. You can just do if shared_state.lock().await, no busy loop, nothing. Tokio will handle the resource management and you know tokio is good at it.
You just need to use tokio::sync::Mutex instead of std::sync::Mutex.

In your solution you have a loop. If you want to change it, please change. Don't try to correct your solution in comments
